# Is it possible to get the difference between width & max-width?

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

Is it possible to get the difference between `width` and `max-width` for a CSS class? For example, let consider the following class:

```css
.className {
  width: 100mm;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

If the container is smaller than 100mm, let's say it is 90mm, then the difference would be 10mm. Then based on that difference apply different styling, similar to as one would with a media query for different screen sizes.

The use case being, `className` is 10% (10mm of 100mm) smaller than expected and there for all sub-components in it need to be scaled down by 10% to maintain their relative size.

If not possible with straight CSS can this be done with SASS/SCSS or maybe stylus or LESS?

Comment: Just out of curiosity did you try using "calc()"?

Comment: `calc(calc(100vw - 100mm) / 100mm)` would get the ratio, but you can't really do `if` logic in CSS (and SASS and the rest are **pre**processors and therefore can't react to real-time changes in width). Since you're using `100vw` as one of the lengths, you could possibly use `@media (max-width: 99mm) { ... }` and do something in there?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the responses. No, we can use calc, unfortunately. With calc, the divisor should be a number (not have any units). I am busy trying out using media queries.

Comment: what kind of styles you want? There is no generic solution to what you want but for specific cases we can do it

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for container queries. They're not a thing, yet. [Hopefully soon](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-3/#container-queries)